# Is it possible to check if an application helper is already set to run at login?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, sandbox

Due to application sandboxing I'm using a helper app to launch my app at login.

I've figured out how to set my helper to start at login. The problem I'm trying to solve now is determining whether or not the helper is ALREADY set to start at login. I don't see anything in the API for that. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

The same API you use to add yourself to the Login Items list, LSSharedFileList, is the one you use to see whether you're already in it. Copy a snapshot of the list and look through it.

Comment: With app sandboxing you can no longer use LSSharedFileList.

See this article: http://www.delitestudio.com/2011/10/25/start-dockless-apps-at-login-with-app-sandbox-enabled/